# Finding the minimum of functions in Python

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, minimum

Hey I have complicated function which takes 4 different argiments and I would like to find values of these arguments for which my function takes the minimum value. For each argument I have bound, for example arg1 must be positive, arg2 must be in interval [0,0.3] itp. So far I use `fmin` but it doesn't support bounds and sometimes I get weird result. Are there any interesting package (I know only scipy.optimize) to job like this?

Comment: What's wrong with scipy.optimise? It seems to have a linear programming function which supports equality and inequality constraints, which is exactly what you're describing

Comment: OK, but are there any other popular packages of this type?

Comment: That is off-topic for SO, try google `python linear programming solvers`